# Java Buttons Pressed in Specific Order

Tags: java, swing, button, passwords, combinations

I have a Jframe in netbeans with 5 buttons, named buttons 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5. I'm trying to make it so if the buttons are pressed in this order 4, 2, 3, 1, it will display a dialogue box. My only problem is getting it to recognize the buttons have been pressed in the correct order.

Comment: Could you wait a moment, I know how to do this, but I have to try it first.

Answer (score 2):

If this were my project, I'd use a `LinkedList<Integer>` or `ArrayList<Integer>` to hold the Integer representing the buttons that have been pushed and in what order, and then would react if the last 5 presses matched the desired pattern. So each button press would add an Integer to the List, and then would check the last 5 entries, and if they match the pattern, *bingo*! show the JOptionPane.

Note that for the best help, you should show us what you've tried, and we can help you refine it.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll try both methods!

Comment: @user2457916: camickr's recommendations and mine are both similar in concept -- you use some structure to hold the value of the pressed button number, for me a collection, and for camickr a StringBuilder. Both would work if implemented correctly. I've 1+'d camickr's answer for this.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you are using buttons for this. Most people would use a `JPasswordTextField`.

If you really want to use buttons. Then you would need to keep a `StringBuilder`. Every time a button is pushed you would add the text of the button to the builder. Then you would check if the toString() of the builder is the password.

If the password is incorrect you would display a JOptionPane and then clear the builder so the user can start again.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

1. Make a global String variable, I named it code, and initialize its value by `""`.
2. On each corresponding button, add code (for button 1) `code+="1;"` and `check();`
3. Create a method `check`, which contains these function:

(If you want the numbers of try limited by 5)

```
System.out.println("Numbers of try: "+code.length());

if(code.length()==5){
  if(code.contains("32415")){
    System.out.println("You made it!!");
  }else{
    code="";
  }
}
```

(If you don't want to limit the numbers of try)

```
if(code.contains("32415")){
  System.out.println("You made it!!");
}
```

Go ahead and try this, it works for me :)

Comment: I can't try it for a bit but it looks like it will defintley work, I'll comment again if it does. Thanks for the help!